# Code Completion not working with Delphi Tokyo

Tags: delphi

I have installed new Tokyo Delphi. I believe there is a bug with the Tokyo IDE. Code completion is not working properly. What you can try is TQuery component. Maybe because it is depreciated but it should work. Also code completion sometimes only works with Uppercase chars after dot.

```
  q := TQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    q.SQL.Text := '...';
    q.FieldByName()
  finally
    q.Free;
  end;
```

When I write this line `q.FieldByName` after dot "." I type "F", I see codes in scroll but if I type "i" after "F", the code completion becomes empty and all is lost.

Comment: Submit a bug report. We can't fix the problem.

Comment: Try using "I", upper case.. If it works, submit a bug report as everyone else has already been pointed out..

Comment: Check if code completion works in another Unit, if so it means that is a problem in your current unit with the uses clauses.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

just find & replace bugged sybols:
"LF
CR" 
with 
"CR LF"

:}

Comment: How are you viewing the CR and LF characters?

Comment: Notepad++:
View -> Show Symbol -> Show All Characters

Comment: Ah ha, that’s what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the IDE has problems with autocompletion.

Did you installed last release of Delphi 10.2.1 and its first patch ?

If you are in debug mode or if there is an erroe in your code, the completion don't work. Try saving your files & project and compiling it.

You can also use Ctrl+Space to force autocompletion popup.

Comment: Well it happens even in a new empty project. Code completion pops and cleans as i write the code. I am using Delphi 10.2 Update 1

Comment: it's perhaps a bug, add a case on https://quality.embarcadero.com/ (or complete an existing opened "completion error" case)

Comment: give up on this product - it has been buggy since C++ Builder 1.0!!!!!!!  This IDE is over 20 years old and they can never seem to get basic functionality right after all these years!